# Using entityGraph with a Session

Tags: java, spring

I have a method (let's call it FOO) that I use a couple of times. 
The result is an entity (let's call it MyEntity) that contains a lot of EAGER columns. 
In one scenario, I want this to fetch in a LAZY way.

1. The problem is that I can't change the entity's Fetch type to LAZY, because most of the times, the EAGER helps, and I can't use entityGraph inside FOO because I want it to be lazy in one scenario. Is there any option to define in advance for a specific session that all the transactions that use MyEntity will be Lazy? (with EntityGraph)
2. This is the code of the fetching -

   ```
       Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class)
               .add(Restrictions.eq("rowType.code", (long) rowType));

       return criteria.list();
   ```

   even if I had a way to know that I'm in  a specific scenario - how can I add the EntityGraph to the session?

Thanks

Comment: The code you show is not using JPA. For EntityGraphs there are plenty of examples, e.g. https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-2-define/

Comment: hi, removed the JPA tag, thx. About the examples - I saw a lot of examples - but in none of them, I saw something that talks about predefine (before criteria) the hints or pass the hints as hidden parameter inside the session to use it in the future.